# How do I decide the frequency of data capture for modeling? How does it affect my final model?

Tags: predictive-modeling, data, linear-regression, machine-learning-model

I plan to capture data to predict energy consumption in a food processing plant. I want to capture production details such as how much each category of food is produced, what is the machine's output, any downtime details etc.
What granularity of data is required for this analysis? I can capture data at five minutes/1 hour or one shift(8 hours). How do I decide on this?
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Granularity of data depends on two things the business use of model you are creating and reliability of data. I would suggest to look at hourly distribution and 8 hourly to see if it follows trend and it does not abrupt noise.So statistically more stable data should.be used to model. If consumption varies very fast then hourly data can be unreliable hence difficult to model

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please elaborate on this? Why specifically 1-hour data?

Comment: Edited, please se now..